# Hibernate doesn't auto-create table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

*pom.xml :*

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

*entity:*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int personId;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
}
```

*application.properties*

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/socialmedia? 
allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver.class=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema = socialmedia
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
```

Hibernate doesn't auto-create tables, I have set the properties and entity classes and the dependencies still the schema remains empty after I run the code. No error messages are shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your strategy is:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
```

This means that Hibernate creates the tables and after the program runs the tables are deleted. That's why you don't see any tables.

You have to use create (only creates tables) or update (also alters the tables):

```
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Then I don't see the JPA starter project in your pom.xml but you have Hibernate dependencies that are not necessary. Your pom.xml should look like:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

spring-boot-starter-data-jpa will autoconfigure Hibernate.

Comment: It's same with `update` or `create` , nothing changes in schema

Comment: I added some more information to my answer. Check it out